# Main differences between Eclipse Indigo SR1 and Sr2

Tags: eclipse-indigo

I've been looking for differences between the two Indigo versions, but I wasn't able to find a clear and concise answer.
I know the important differences between Indigo and Indigo SR1, like Java 7 support. But I can't figure out differences between SR1 and SR2.
Can someone help me ?
thanx, William.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse Indigo SR2 - also known as Eclipse 3.7.2 - is primary a bug fix release from SR1, so there should be *no* major changes. Most notably, SR2 should be completely backwards compatible with SR1.
But you can always look at the official [release note for Eclipse Classic 3.7.2](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_3.7.2.html) - at the bottom, you can find the bugs fixed in the release.

There are no explicit release notes for the various packaged editions of Eclipse (EPP), but you can get a very good idea about the changes by searching [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) for the EPP project. E.g. all the changes in the RCP/RAP edition is found [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced;list_id=808089;component=rcp-package;product=EPP). By playing a little with the search criteria - especially the `target milestone` - you can find the changes relevant for a specific release.

Arjan Tijms also listed some of the important [changes](http://jdevelopment.nl/eclipse-37-sr2-released/) in his blog.